# Nested JSON object deserialization inSpring-boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am facing some issue with deserializing a nested JSON in Spring-boot which comes as a request body.

can anybody help me, please?

Below is the structure of the JSON.

```
{
  "service": {
    "week": {
      "sunday": "onene",
      "monday": "two",
      "tuesday": "three"
    },
    "body": {
      "parts": {
        "head": "one",
        "hand": "two"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Do I need to create a POJO of Parts and use it as a variable in body, then a Week POJO and finally use the object type of week and body in Service POJO? Will that work?

Or is there any better way?

I'm sorry, I cannot post the actual JSON here. So I have provided a sample structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I found the solution to this. 
Let me explain.
The correct approach is having a nested POJO. 
Parts POJO will have its fields, head and hand.
Then comes the body POJO which will have a field of Type Parts as according to the given sample JSON.
Now there will be another POJO, Week with its field (Sunday, Monday and Tuesday). Now there will be another Service POJO which will have Week and Body type fields.

Well, I was correct, until here.

The mistake I did was that **I overlooked the very first enclosing curly braces**.
Yes, there will be another POJO (say Root) which will have a field of Service type.
This was the missing key.

Anyway, I just wanted you to go through this so that you can understand about the missing piece.

Finally, the best part is, there is an online link through which you can generate all the POJO with proper structure out of the given JSON input.

Here goes the link. 
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

Answer (score 0):

Yes the pojo structure should be as you described in the question :

```
class Service {

private Week week;
private Body body;

//setters,getters and constructors

}
```

and also declare the POJO classes for Week and Body as well with their corresponding instance fields.

Comment: I already implemented that. But getting null everywhere. Anyway, I'll try it again.

Answer (score 0):

To deserialize that kind of a structure you will need

```
class Body {
    private Service service;
}

class Service {
    private Week week;
    private Map<String, String> parts;
}

class Week {
    private String sunday;
    private String monday;
    private String tuesday;
    private String wednesday;
    private String thursday;
    private String friday;
    private String saturday;
}
```

As you can see we can use  Map structure to deserialize parts, however if parts are only contains predefined keys you can create a class for it.
Make sure you created setters and getters for every field

Comment: Cannot we have Parts pojo too? Is it necessary to take parts as a map?

Comment: @AshishSingh You can use POJO if all keys are known if you need more flexible way to store it, the map is good for it

Answer (score 0):

You need to create POJO and use @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) at class level in the POJO. This annotation will ignore the unknown properties.

com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties